# Accessing SQL Server 2012 from php under Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in troubles...

I have a web server apache/php under linux, also i have another server with SQL Server database under windows. I need to get access to SQL Server database from my apache/php.

What do i need, please help. I have no idea how to start.

**sorry for my english.

Comment: googling can be a good start point: https://www.google.com/search?q=Accessing+SQL+Server+2012+from+php+under+Linux

Comment: of course my firts step was this but i can't be able to do the conection. I found something about sql server driver but it is not clear what can i do ... ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Could do with a bit more clarification but I'll try my best..

If you mean through the code, you would do it like this:

Create a new php file called "connect.php" and insert all of this code, replacing the tags like USERNAME with the correct details.

```
 <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

 // Create connection
 $con = mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }


 $select_db = mysqli_select_db($con, 'DATABASE');
 if (!$select_db){
 die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($con));
 }
 ?>
```

Next, EVERY file that requires a connection to the database, simply add

```
 include("connect.php"):
```

To it at the start of the page and it should be fine :)
I seriously recommend you read up a bit more though as you seem like a bit of a newb (we all started somewhere)!

Hope this is what you were after!

Comment: thanks for helping but i need to do the conection with **SQL Server 2012**. I already have conection with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Look for dblib, you will need to add that driver.